# Создание пользователя с доступом только к одной схеме. POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

Суть проблемы: мне нужно создать пользователя, который будет иметь доступ только к одной схеме.

Пояснение: у меня есть база данных newsredaction и в ней две схемы с идентичными таблицами public и tests, так вот мне надо создать пользователя, который будет иметь доступ только к схеме tests, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, желательно подробно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Права на схему

Схема `public` - особая, по-умолчанию права `usage` и `create` для неё выданы всем. псевдороли `public`. И пока есть права `public` - отзывать их для отдельных пользователей смысла нет. Поэтому начать необходимо с выяснения каким пользователям эта схема нужна. предоставить им явные права:

```
grant usage on schema public to needuser;
```

Для тех кто должен иметь право создавать новые объекты в схеме:

```
grant create on schema public to needuser;
```

Затем отозвать публичные права:

```
revoke ALL on SCHEMA public FROM public;
```

Теперь нужному пользователю добавляем права на схему tests:

```
grant usage on schema tests to needuser;
```

Строго говоря на тто как вопрос сформулирован - это и есть ответ.

Обратите внимание: это права только и строго на схему, на объекты в этой схеме они повлияют только тем, что без права usage вы не можете использовать объекты в схеме, но обратное неверно. Имя право usage вы можете не иметь права на объекты в схеме.

### Права на объекты в схеме

Вы не указали, что именно вы имеете в виду под "будет иметь доступ". Предположу что CRUD таблиц: select, insert, update, delete:

```
 grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on ALL tables in schema tests TO needuser;
 grant SELECT, USAGE on ALL sequences in schema tests TO needuser;
```

### Права на новые объекты в схеме

На предыдущем шаге выдали права для уже существующих таблиц. Но если вы создадите новую таблицу - никто права на неё пользователю не даст. Можно попросить. Но только если вы точно знаете кто конкретно будет добавлять объекты:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres GRANT SELECT,USAGE ON SEQUENCES  TO needuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON TABLES  TO needuser;
```

### Функции

Хранимые процедуры создаются так же с правами execute для public. Поэтому если в этой схеме вы создаёте хранимые процедуры - вам необходимо это учитывать. Делать revoke execute либо оставлять пользователю возможность их вызова.

### Группы пользователей

Если вам может понадобиться несколько таких пользователей - то будет удобнее создать сначала роль и все права выдать на эту роль (всё то же самое, вместо имени пользователя можно указывать им роли). Затем назначить пользователю эту роль:

```
grant needuser to user1;
```

И пользователь user1 сразу получит все настроенные права этой роли.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Да, Вы правильно поняли, я имел ввиду CRUD доступ

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | TRUNCATE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
[, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
ON { [ TABLE ] имя_таблицы [, ...]
     | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA имя_схемы [, ...] }
TO указание_роли [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-grant